# How do I sort and print the phrases along the rating given in descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I managed to write the code below which works, however when printing, it only prints the ratings in order but not the sentences. How do I sort the sentences along the rating given in order??

```
public static void loopswithinloops()   
{

    String[] sentences = {"I am blessed to have you in my life. You are the one thing in my life that is true and real",
                    "I am honoured to have you by my side to love and to cherish each day of our lives.", 
                    "More precious than any other thing in my life is to see your face each and every day",
                    "To wake up beside you is a treasure that I have found in you and that I am thankful for.",
                    "Your beautiful eyes dance bright and clear and I can see forever in your eyes." };

    for (int i=0; i<=1; i++)    
    {
    ratemessage(sentences);  //this will loop the whole rating message two times from 0 to 1.
    }       

}

public static void ratemessage (String[] sentences) // this will receive the argument from the method defined above and then be printed below as shown.

{   
    int[] result = new int[sentences.length];//you have to give the array a size
    String inputStr;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sentences[i]);//the sentences one at at time 
        inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("what do you rate this sentence out of 10?");
        result[i] = (int)Float.parseFloat(inputStr);//put the input into the array - it comes as a float so you'll have to cast it to int
     } 

    sort (result, sentences);
    printsort (result, sentences);

}

public static void sort( int [] result , String [] sentences)
{
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < (result.length -i); j++)
        {
            //if numbers[j-1] > numbers[j], swap the elements
            if(result[j-1] > result[j])
            {
                temp = result[j-1];
                result[j-1]=result[j];
                result[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void printsort (int [] result , String [] sentences)
{
System.out.println("The ratings go in ascending order: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Your ascending rating is " + result[i]+ " " + sentences[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can sort sentences in the same time you are sorting result. Ask yourself why the sort method has both parameters and why the second is never used.

Comment: True but I don't know where to include the second one in the sort method, and how to go about it. @Mooolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just supplying the code to fix this specific issue, I will give a pointer on how to restructure it to make it much more intuitive. I'm using Java 8 features but it's easy to convert back if required.

Create a class that holds both the message and the rating.

```
public class RatedMessage {
    private final String message;
    private final int rating;

    public RatedMessage(String message, int rating) {
        this.message = message;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return rating + ": " + message;
    }

    public static int compareRating(RatedMessage rm1, RatedMessage rm2) {
        return rm1.rating - rm2.rating;
    }
}
```

Then create a list of RatedMessage objects

```
List<RatedMessage> ratedMessages = new ArrayList<>();
```

Alter your message rating method to create a RatedMessage for each rated message and add it to the list.

```
ratedMessages.add(new RatedMessage(message, rating));
```

Then sort your list using the rating:

```
Collections.sort(ratedMessages, RatedMessage::compareRatings);
```

Then print out the sorted list:

```
ratedMessages.stream().map(RatedMessage::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```